What happens if you rest in extreme cold?
As I understand it, a high-level spellcaster travelling in a blizzard can avoid cold damage using Investiture of Ice. However, the spell goes away if they rest, which they inevitably need to do. What happens if they rest? Do they freeze?
From what @MissMisinforma wrote in the chat room, the rules do say:

Some special abilities and environmental hazards, such as starvation and the long-term effects of freezing or scorching temperatures, can lead to a special condition called exhaustion. Exhaustion is measured in six levels. An effect can give a creature one or more levels of exhaustion, as specified in the effect's description.

However, resting removes exhaustion, so it seems the spellcaster should have no problems trekking through the blizzard (?) Or they can use a spell such as Fireball to generate the heat to let them rest in comfort (??)
I'm not very familiar with D&D, so this question might have basic issues. If so, an answer pinpointing what the issues are would still be appreciated.

"I expect you to die, Mister Bond."

The wizard archetype is that they are at their most powerful with preparation. If a wizard is caught in a blizzard by surprise then even at a high level the wizard is going to be in trouble. If they have time to prepare then you can bet that they'll want mundane protection like fur-lined clothes and boots, rather than relying solely on spells.

You would have to roll to see if you survive the night
There is a lot to unpack in your question, so let me go bit by bit. First off:
blizzards are described along with the effects of cold weather on page 10 and 11 of Icewind Dale - Rime of the Frostmaiden. Cold weather is also described in the Dungeons Master's Guide. A blizzard imposes a number of different negative effects, such as limiting visibility or making travel harder, however they do not deal cold damage, nor do they give levels of exhaustion. Therefore blizzards are irrelevant to your question, instead we will take a look at cold weather, which reads in the DMG on page 110:

Whenever the temperature is at or below 0 degrees Fahrenheit, a creature exposed to the cold must succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw at the end of each hour or gain one level of exhaustion.

This means a character traveling in extreme cold weather must make a special roll, called a saving throw, using their constitution attribute each hour. If they fail this roll they gain one level of exhaustion, which as you linked, gives a number of detrimental effects, ending with death at 6 levels of exhaustion. Though this roll only has a DC (Difficulty Class) of 10 (meaning you have to roll a 10 or higher to succeed), which is actually pretty easy, but having to do this 24 times in a day, you are bound to fail some times and as soon as you fail this 6 times without removing exhaustion, you will die.
How to remove exhaustion
The rules for exhaustion on page 291 of the PHB (Player's Handbook) read:

Finishing a long rest reduces a creature's exhaustion level by 1

So if your wizard wakes up in the morning, this will remove a single level of exhaustion. They however also had to do 8 of these saving throws during the night, so that one time reduction is probably not going to mean much.
Note that there are other ways to remove exhaustion, see this question for more details. The Greater Restoration being the most interesting one here, this spell is however not available to Wizards, so he will typically not be able to use it, to remove his exhaustion.
How to survive in cold weather
My above statements are all talking about a wizard who is unprepared for the cold weather. The rules about cold weather stated earlier explain further:

Creatures with resistance to or immunity to cold damage automatically succeed on the saving throw, as do creatures wearing cold weather gear

This leaves us with a number of options to not gain exhaustion, while traveling in cold weather:

Have resistance or immunity to Cold damage. So if your wizard is a Silver Dragonborn for example, they will never have to make saving throws. The spell you linked also allows for this, note however that Investiture of Ice only lasts 10 minutes, so it will only help with a maximum of 1 saving throw, and since this is a 6th level spell the wizard will, depending on their level, not be able to cast it more than a handful of times per day.
Wear cold weather gear This gear is also described in Rime of the Frostmaiden and costs only 10 gold pieces. Simply wearing this will prevent you from getting any exhaustion in cold weather.
Keep the temperature above 0 degrees Fahrenheit. As stated in the earlier quote, the Saving throw is only required if the temperature is sufficiently low. Meaning if your wizard carries enough torches or uses spells like Create Bonfire they can easily survive the cold as well. This spell is also a cantrip, so they can use it as many times as they want. They could also use a Tent, which can be bought for 2 gp or use a spell like Tiny Hut which creates a "comfortable" atmosphere to keep the cold away from them. The Fireball spell you mentioned is probably not going to be a help here, as its duration is instantaneous, meaning its heat is only there for a brief moment.


Hmm this actually makes it seem like even an unprepared Wizard can trek through the blizzard without issue by resting immediately and take that time to prepare Tiny Hut / Create Bonfire. They'd have to make 8 constitution rolls, but they can fail seven of those since they lose 1 level of exhaustion, so odds are they survive. Afterwards they can just cast Tiny Hut, rest (lose 1 level of exhaustion), cast another Tiny Hut, rest, etc, until they're able to travel with Create Bonfire as a heat source.

@Allure They can only prepare Tiny Hut if it is in there spellbook and Create Bonfire is a cantrip, so either they know it, or they don't. They cannot fail 7 saving throws, if they fail 6 they are dead, so they can only fail 5. The 1 level is only deducted once the rest is finished.

@Allure you can only benefit from long rest once per 24 hours, also note that 3 levels of exhaustion give you disadvantage on saving throws, making it easier to fail the subsequent ones, and 5 levels reduce your speed to 0 so you won't be going anywhere anytime soon if you let it get this far. And the bonfire from Create Bonfire doesn't move so you can't exactly travel with it, the best you could do is repeatedly cast it in front of you or something + it only last up to 1 minute

@AnnaAG right, but you could prepare three Tiny Huts and stay inside for 24 hours until you can long rest again. It still seems possible to me, unless the initial saving throws fail and they die (TreeSpawned's math is better than mine there). Create Bonfire might not even be necessary: the wizard could trek until they fail a saving throw, then Tiny Hut up and wait/rest 24 hours to remove that level of exhaustion.

@Allure sure but you won't be doing much travelling this way, better just get yourself a set of winter clothes and you can trek all day without worrying

@Allure another thing to take into account is time. This kind of method is going to take days upon days, since you'll essentially need to wait 24h to remove each point of exhaustion, and that's not taking into account the slow travel pace this enforces, as AnnaAG mentions above. If there's some kind of time limit on the campaign or current quest, this isn't gonna cut it.

Protection from Energy gets you resistance for an hour, and as a 3rd level spell a high level wizard can cast it a good handful of times

Want to point out, while the benefits of a tent are up to the DM, real world a tent will do very little to protect you from cold.  Wind, yes; rain, yes; cold, not so much, at least not unless there is a heat source in the tent.

Gotta disagree with Jack here, since there is a source of heat in the tent: you. In my experience, even with a nylon tent, the air inside can be 5-10 degrees warmer. And adventurers are much more likely to be carrying a canvas tent, which is significantly better at trapping heat.

I'll try to answer the underlying question of "how should a wizard travel through cold environs." While you're asking about a high-level spellcaster, I'm interested in the subject of multiple level options.
Cantrips only
At this point, your options are pretty damn limited.
Traveling:

Use Create Bonfire to create a bonfire every X feet. This will
keep you plenty warm, at the cost of slowing down your movement
significantly. The tradeoff is how cold you're willing to get. If you space the bonfires every ~15 feet, you'll be pretty consistently warm, and get to move reasonably quickly, casting a new bonfire 15 feet away from yourself every 30 feet you travel. If you're moving at a nominal Normal pace of 300ft/minute, that's  10 castings, or an additional 60 seconds, so an effective speed of 1.5mph. If you're in an active blizzard, you might end up having to cast the bonfire every 10 feet, which will slow you down considerably, but should still work. Given my experience w/ bonfires and cold weather, I can't imagine weather cold enough that being five feet away from a five-foot-cube-sized bonfire won't keep you warm.

Resting:

If you only need to rest in the cold, then making a shelter with Mold Earth seems pretty plausible to me. You do need loose earth, so if the soil is frozen, heat it up ~1 cubic ft at a time with prestidigitation, and build yourself a dugout-type structure. If you're traveling over solid rock, you're shit out of luck.

1st level spells:
Traveling:

Command or Charm Person to get some cold weather gear from someone. Or threaten them with one of the damage spells, but that's cheating.

Resting: Only an option for Bards, Druids, and Rangers, but Animal Friendship should let you find some nice fuzzy creatures to sleep in a pile with, or to rest in their sheltered hidey hole. Unlike Charm Person, it lasts 24 hrs!
Other useful spells: Whatever your clothing situation, Find Familiar to tuck a cat into your shirt will really help you stay warm. Extra bodies, extra heat.
2nd level spells:
Traveling:

Locate Object on cold weather apparel will make it much easier to find someone to Charm into giving you it.
Heat Metal on some hefty chunks of something with high heat capacitance will let you carry something hot with you, which should make life a little more comfortable. Just make sure not to make physical contact with it.
Resting:
Didn't find any really good upgrades here. Heat Metal will be less unpleasant to warm up your earthen shelter with than a bonfire or Control Flame, certainly.

3rd level spells:
Traveling:

I didn't think of any bonus good options here.

Resting:

This is the level at which resting becomes trivial. Tiny Hut, Galder's Tower, and Meld into Stone should all protect you from the elements. No point in exploring options past these, you're not going to beat Tiny Hut or Tower (if your DM will let you have it).

4th level spells:

We finally unlock some less gimmicky travel options. Fabricate yourself some warm clothes out of wool. You can even take Locate Creature to find something wooly first!

5th Level Spells:

Creation is also a good option for making some warm clothing, though I'd rather have wool than vegetable-based warm clothing. That said, allegedly, milkweed floss is a great insulator on par with down.
Planar Binding on something firey will make for a good traveling companion, which you can obtain with Summon Greater Elemental.
If you're moving through a forest, Tree Stride is incredibly good for traversing short distances quickly.

6th level spells:

Transport Via Plants is like Ultimate Tree Stride, albeit one use.
I feel like Wind Walk should let you safely traverse a cold area, but it doesn't explicitly give you cold resistance, so DM fiat applies.

7th Level spells:

Etherealness will definitely protect you from the elements, as it keeps the physical world from affecting you.
Teleport. Nuff said.

8th level spells

Control Weather can turn weather within 5 miles of you from an arctic blizzard to merely a cold raid.

Weirdly, not a lot of other improvements, but you already have teleport!
9th Level Spell

At long last, we get the most powerful cold-weather spell: Shapechange. Turn yourself into a triton, a player class with cold-resistance! Or, a dragon. You know, whatever works.
Wish for cold resistance. Or just for the weather to be nice.

If anyone has suggestions for things to add, please comment!

At 7th level, Magnificent Mansion is a great option for resting.  It lasts longer than Tiny Hut and also provides food.

It's not the question I asked, but I +1ed because it was an interesting answer anyway. Next I'll wonder how a high-level spellcaster might travel through scorching heat =)
